# How to get records by using foreign key in one table using primery key another table in visual basic 6.0

Tags: sql, vb6, ms-access-2007

i have two tables in same database:

- table1 contains `order_no(primery key)` and `cust_name`
- table2 contains `order_no(foreign key)` (which also have duplicates entry per food item ordered in single order), `table_no`, `items`, `date`, `cust_name` and so on...

so my question is how can i show the records in listbox and datagrid or in textbox using table1's primery key `order_no` so i can get all the records which have assigned the foreign key with same order number in table2

i am using visual basic 6.0

Comment: Sounds like an `INNER JOIN`, you can find lots of examples on the internet. The `INNER JOIN` keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables (`order_no`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Private Sub mLoadData(lOrder_no As Long)
    ' add a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library
    ' add a MSHFLXGD (Microsoft Hierarchical FlexGrid) control named grData to form
    Dim rc As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim db As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim sConnString As String, sSQL As String

    'sConnString = create a connection string according to your database - https://www.connectionstrings.com/
    db.Open sConnString

    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE order_no =" & lOrder_no
    Set rc = db.Execute(sSQL)
    Set grData.DataSource = rc

End Sub
```

Comment: This is only retriving data from table2...i want access data from table1 using primery key

Comment: He's given you all the VB6 code you need, you can go a little further and modify the SELECT statement.

Comment: sSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & table_name & " WHERE order_no =" & lOrder_no

Comment: And I recommend a parameterized query if the user can input the number there (although it doensn't look this way - [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014834/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-on-following-code-in-visual-basic-2012)).