# Visual Basic Group by

Tags: sql, group-by, vb6

Need help...

```
Table Name - cashbook
Field name - pname & amount
```

Examble

```
pname              amount
Antony              1500
Jose                3000
Antony              3500
```

need to display in msflexgrid like belo

```
Antony - 5000
Jose   - 3000
```

below my code is not working....can anybody help me

```vb
Rec.open "select  from pname,sum(amount) as amt from cashbook group by pname order by pname,var,adopendynamic,adlockoptimist"

While rec.eof=false
    Pymnt.rows=pymnt.rows+1
    Pymnt.textmatrix(pymnt.rows -1,0)=rec!pname
    Pymnt.textmatrix(pymnt.rows -1,1)=amt
    Rec.movenext
Wend
Rec.close
```

Comment: That's not VB.NET, the question isn't about VB at all but rather SQL, and I just had to do quite a bit of work to clean up your post.  Not a good start, I'm afraid.  Also, saying that something doesn;t work is never adequate.  You should spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a good question.

Comment: I can't remember that far back, but is your Rec.open correct? Should it just be the sql that is quoted, rather than the options?

Comment: Please clarify "not working". There is an example with MSHFlexGrid (Microsoft Hierarchical FlexGrid) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58236410/how-to-get-records-by-using-foreign-key-in-one-table-using-primery-key-another-t

Answer (score 1):

I made a few fixes to your code and came up with the following:

```
Public Sub Test()
   rec.Open "select pname, sum(amount) as amt from cashbook group by pname order by pname", var, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

   While Not rec.EOF
      pymnt.Rows = pymnt.Rows + 1
      pymnt.textmatrix(pymnt.Rows - 1, 0) = rec.Fields("pname").Value
      pymnt.textmatrix(pymnt.Rows - 1, 1) = rec.Fields("amt").Value
      rec.MoveNext
   Wend

   rec.Close
End Sub
```

The fixes I made include:

1. Constructing a proper SQL statement
2. Supplying the correct parameters to the `Open` method
3. Assuming `var` is an open `Connection` object
4. Correcting the spelling of `adLockOptimistic`
5. Changing how the data is accessed in the loop